# xmlhttprequest internal server error

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I have xmlhttprequest code which is communicating with file in sharepoint 14 hive folder.and is working very well on other computers except mine.
running on ie10, not sure what is wrong with my environment.or if I am missing any setting that is required to get it to work.

Note: running on ie8 ie9 is same result.

Comment: share you code that will help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Provide me with your code, Only then I would be able to help you.I am not sure what are you trying to do with xmlhttprequest code. If you  are using xmlhttprequest variable in your code, you can try following check for different browsers.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

The if statement runs through for those browsers which support xmlhttprequest. And else statement is for those browsers which don't support xmlhttprequest.